# cmake cannot open file optimized.lib when trying to add Boost Process

Tags: windows, boost, cmake

I'm creating a C++ Windows service.
I would like to add Boost Process to my application, but for some reason I keep getting this error:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'optimized.lib'

Everything worked fine before I tried adding Boost. When I open my Visual Studio solution, I notice the application is trying to link with an `optimized.lib` and a `debug.lib` library that I am unfamiliar with. CMake only tries to link with these libraries when I try to add Boost.

My directory structure:

```
UpdateService/
    CMakeLists.txt
    app/
        CMakeLists.txt
        Driver.cpp
    build/
    include/
        stdafx.h
        UpdateService/
            # a bunch of *.h files
    src/
        CMakeLists.txt
        # a bunch of *.cpp files
```

My `UpdateService/CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12...3.14)
if(${CMAKE_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 3.12)
    cmake_policy(VERSION ${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION})
endif()

project(UpdateService
        VERSION 1.0
        DESCRIPTION "Service that runs the update manager"
        LANGUAGES CXX)

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(app)
set_property(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY VS_STARTUP_PROJECT UpdateService)
```

My `UpdateService/src/CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12...3.14)
if(${CMAKE_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 3.12)
    cmake_policy(VERSION ${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION})
endif()

set(FMT_DIR "E:/Repositories/fmt-5.3.0")
set(FMT_INCLUDE "${FMT_DIR}/include")
set(SPDLOG_INCLUDE "E:/Repositories/spdlog/include")

set(Boost_DEBUG ON)
# set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
# set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME ON)
find_package(Boost 1.67 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system filesystem)

# Needed to suppress a warning in boost process.
add_compile_definitions(_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)

add_library(UpdateServiceLib STATIC
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/stdafx.h"
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/UpdateService/CLI11.hpp"
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/UpdateService/Config.h"
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/UpdateService/CmdParams.h"
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/UpdateService/LogUtils.h"
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/UpdateService/ServiceBase.h"
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/UpdateService/UpdateService.h"
    "${FMT_DIR}/src/format.cc"
    "Config.cpp"
    "CmdParams.cpp"
    "LogUtils.cpp"
    "ServiceBase.cpp"
    "UpdateService.cpp")

target_include_directories(UpdateServiceLib PUBLIC 
    "${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}"
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include"
    "${FMT_INCLUDE}"
    "${SPDLOG_INCLUDE}")

target_link_libraries(UpdateServiceLib PUBLIC "${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
```

My `UpdateService/app/CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12...3.14)
if(${CMAKE_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 3.12)
    cmake_policy(VERSION ${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION})
endif()

add_executable(UpdateService "Driver.cpp")

target_include_directories(UpdateService 
    PRIVATE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include" "${FMT_INCLUDE}" "${SPDLOG_INCLUDE}")

target_link_libraries(UpdateService PRIVATE UpdateServiceLib)
```

I am building the project with something like this:

```
rmdir /S /Q build
mkdir build
mkdir build\x64
pushd build\x64
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" ..\..
cmake --build . --config Debug
popd
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove **double quotes** around `${Boost_LIBRARIES}`.

Double quotes tells CMake to treat enclosed value as a **single parameter**, but `Boost_LIBRARIES` is actually a list (multivalue variable).

---

Normally, double quotes are used only for:

- "string literals" (when an argument contains no variables' *dereferences*), e.g.

  ```
  "abc"
  ```
- when it is definitely known that an argument represents a single value, e.g.

  ```
  "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include"
  ```

Plural number for "LIBRARIES" word implies that `Boost_LIBRARIES` variable *may* contain multiple values, so do not enclose it with double quotes.

Comment: This and messing with the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` did the trick.